# SideBar Menu Button move with scroll, and at bottom

Tags: html, css

I've been using this [demo](https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/responsive-navigation-menu) to create a sidebar menu.

I wanted to add a button at the bottom of the sidemenu; but the problem is that as the list is expanded the button does not move with the scrollbar. i.e it overlaps

The html part

```
<div class="logout">
    <li>
        <a>
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></i> LOGOUT
         </a>
    </li>
 </div>
```

The css part

```
.nav-side-menu .logout{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 300px;
}
```

Comment: Can you make a full demo with the sidebar, thanks

Comment: https://bootsnipp.com/user/snippets/4n7aK

Comment: That site requires an account - could you add in jsfiddle or codepen, or better, stackoverflow snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the assumption it is a responsive menu and you don't know the height of the user's screen and want it to fill the height entirely, this is how I would change your snippet:

https://bootsnipp.com/user/snippets/Ez3RD

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on the link you provided. Just place the div OUTSIDE of the last UL tag.

HTML

```
<div class="bottom-icon">
    <button style="height:30px; width:100px; background-color:#2888ff; color:#fff;">Hello World</button>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.bottom-icon {
    text-align:center;
    padding-top:30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add div tag below the last li tag. and It works successfully there no overlap.